# Firebase database synchronous calls issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to the firebase. I am using the firebase database. In which i have two nodes one which has the users information and second which has all the comments on a post from users.  These are the database structure

**Users Node**

[image: Users node]

**Comments Node**
[image: Comments node]

What i want to do is fetch all the comments of a post and then take the `from_key` which is actually the user key who has commented on the post from that comment node and then get that particular user info from firebase. I have written following code.

```
$(".all_firebase_keys").each(function () {
                    database.ref('comments/' + $(this).val()).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
                        values = snapshot.val();
                        console.log(values.comment);
                        snapshot.forEach(function (path) {
                            if (path.key == "from_key") {
                                database.ref('users/' + values.from_key).once("value", function (user) {
                                    console.log(values.comment + "  " + user.val());
                                });
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });
```

The issue which i am facing is that as firebase calls are asynchronous it is not doing calls in the correct order. I want to make it synchronous like first fetch comments and then for each comment fetch user details and then go on to the next comment. Please help me how can i achieve it i have already spent so much time on it by looking for the solution and at-last posting it here. It is not a duplicate of some other question.

**Current Output**

1. Comment 1
2. Comment 2
3. User a
4. User b

**The output which i want**

1. comment 1 User a
2. comment 2 User b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I managed to find the solution on own my with the help of this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY&t=0s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=6). I am sharing the helping link and my code maybe it will be helpful for some other person.

```
$(".all_firebase_keys").each(function () {
            id = "#"+$(this).val();
            commentsRef.child($(this).val()).orderByChild('timestamp').on("child_added", function (snap) {
               users = usersRef.child(snap.val().from_key);
               users.once("value", function (snapshot) {

                   $("#"+snap.ref.parent.key).append('<p>'+snapshot.val().first_name +" "+ snap.val().comment+'</p>');
               })
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like Promises.

Maybe something like this:

```
    $(".all_firebase_keys").each(function () {
                database.ref('comments/' + $(this).val()).on('child_added', async function (snapshot) {
                    values = snapshot.val();
                    console.log(values.comment);

                    for (value of values) {
                        data = await database.ref('users/' + value.from_key).once("value");

                         console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

It just example. Use for method not forEach.

Comment: @Emestyno Its still having the same issue.